# stop route in otherwise

Tags: apache-camel

hi have a route like this

```
<route id="route1">
<from uri="activemq:queuer1"/>
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${header.urn} regex '^user*'</simple>
            <to uri="xslt:classpath:/xslt/rdf/user.xsl"/>
        </when>
        <when>
            <simple>${header.urn} regex '^userdata:.*'</simple>
            <to uri="xslt:classpath:/xslt/rdf/userdata.xsl"/>
        </when>
        ....
        <otherwise>
            <setHeader headerName="errorMsg ">
                <constant>no xsl file for this type</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="activemq:error"/>
        </otherwise> 
    </choice>
    <process ref="importer"/>
</route>
```

Now if the route goes into the otherwise part, the message should not be processed.
Can I somehow stop the route if message goes into the otherwise ?

On possibility would be I add the process part in all the when parts and delete it at the end.
But we have already several when parts and more to come.

Other solution would be prefered.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add a `<stop/>` to stop continue routing the message.

In Java code:

```
exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);
```

In Java DSL:

```
.when(simple("${in.header.CamelHttpResponseCode} == 404"))
    .stop()
.otherwise()
    ...
```

Comment: This is a really useful technique. Is it possible to add this documentation to the Camel web site? It might already be there but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I couldn't find this in the documentation either, although there's an example of it in Claus's book.

Comment: This source might help: [Intercept](http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html)

Comment: Documentation of [Stop EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/stop-eip.html) from 3.14 (LTS)