# Camel: SpringDSL shutdown route on com.my.FatalException or its subcleass

Tags: apache-camel

Using Camel 11, likely will upgrade to 13.0:

Req: If some part of route throws a FatalException or its subclass, the route should be stopped. How do I express this in **onExpression** section of SpringDSL. If that is not the right place, what is the right place to do that?

```
    <onException>

        <exception>eri.odapp.OdAppFatalException or its subclass</exception>

        <log loggingLevel="ERROR" message="A fatal error happend in route <routeName> while processing file: ${header.CamelFileName}, Shutting down the route  " />

        <!--  Shut down the route where this fatal exception happened (so admins can rectify the scenario and restart the flow)-->

    </onException>
```

Fatal Exception Hierarchy:

```
public class OdAppException extends RuntimeException 
public class OdAppIOException extends OdAppFatalException
public class OdAppDataAccessException extends OdAppFatalException
```

Comment: i dont know if there is something in xml for stopRoute but you can delegate the task of stopping the route to a bean in your onException clause.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different context than your question, but perhaps this thread this would be applicable?

[Stop routing in otherwise clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830390/stop-route-in-otherwise)

Also may be of interest:

[camel FAQ on stopping routes](http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html)

(note: might have made this a comment rather than an answer but don't yet have that option due to points/reputation)