# JBoss Fuse ESB: persist and compare messages

Tags: java, jboss, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I just started developing my first JBoss Fuse project and I would like to ask you a pretty general question regarding my intention to process the messages.

I already receive data in form of XML files and unmarshal them to get Java Pojos. Now I'd like to compare the current message with the previous one to check if a certain attribute in the XML has changed. So I only want the message to be continued within the route if the value is different from the value of the message before.

Could you tell me what the best and most performant method (persistence?) would be to achieve this kind of processing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of would be use a POJO bean in your route that stores the received message/object in a [member variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html). Your route will contain just 1 instance of the POJO which will be called for all messages flowing through the route. This means you can keep state information in the POJO. In your case, store the message in a member variable so you can compare it with the next message when it comes in.

See here for info on how to stop a message from being processed any further: [stop route in otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830390/stop-route-in-otherwise)